# Python win32com retrieve mail from alternate mail box (outlook 2013)

Tags: python, outlook, win32com

I am trying to switch to a specific mailbox before retrieving the latest email from the Inbox of that mailbox.

I have the following code working in Outlook 2010 but when I use the same on Outlook 2013 I get the exception 'AttributeError: Folders instance has no **call** method' on the 3rd line

```
folderName = "My MailBox Name"
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
folder = outlook.Folders(folderName)
```

Is this a change from outlook 2010 to 2013?

Are there any alternative/workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Try `folder = outlook.Folders.Item(folderName)` instead.